# Creating an array of links using zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier

I have a use case in Zapier with typeform in which I'm receiving between 2-30(essentially an unknown number) links to files in the typeform and want to put them in an array using zapier.

I get the links in text through the body html(defined as a body field in the inputData) of a notification email. Each link comes in the following format:

```
<a href=\'https://admin.typeform.com/form/results/file/download/<FORMNUMBER>/<VARIABLE>/<FILENAME>.pdf\'>report.pdf</a>
```

I've done this but I keep getting null:

```
output = [{id: 123, hello: "world"}];
var array_of_matches = inputData.body.match(/href="([^"]*")/g);
console.log(array_of_matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML has single quotes for the `href` value but the regex is trying to match double quotes. Try `match(/href='([^']*')/g);` instead.